# Magento XML RPC Error

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, xml-rpc

I have created an XML-RPC User and I've assigned a role (with all resources) from admin panel: System/Web Services/XML-Rpc Users and Roles.

Now I want to dump all cart products and send them to an external server.

I'm using this code in app/design/frontend/default/theme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml:

```
$client = new Zend_XmlRpc_Client('http://mysite/api/xmlrpc/', 80);
$session = $client->call('login', array('myuser', 'myapi'));
$filterData = array('type' => array('in' => 'simple'));
$product = $client->call('call', array($session, 'category_product.list', array($filterData)));
var_dump($product);
$server = new Zend_XmlRpc_Client('/xmlServer.php','www.server-site.com', 80);
$result = $server->send($product);
```

The problem is that I receive this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getUri() on a non-object in /var/www/html/zzz/lib/Zend/XmlRpc/Client.php on line 265
```

This is the code from line 265:

```
if($http->getUri() === null) {
        $http->setUri($this->_serverAddress);
    }
```

I think that the problem comes from here:

```
$session = $client->call('login', array('myuser', 'myapi'));
```

But the user and api are valid. So I don't know what could it be.
What is wrong in my code?

Anticipated thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is my server configuration.
It returns false if I try this php command: file_get_contents
So host can't be accessed on port 80.
It's because of the firewall or some other settings.